# Changing backround color of button when click on the radio button in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have an online exam form where there are questions with a number and four radio buttons with answers. And also button which I created at runtime. Remaining control which I created at design time.

The main problem is that I want to change the button background color when I click an answer, i.e. radio button. Suppose if the question is 10 then the button number 10 color will be changed when I click the 10 answer, i.e. click on the radiobutton.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    RadioButton1.Checked = False
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To 5

        Dim b1 As New Button
        b1.Name = "butt" & i
        b1.Width = 30
        b1.Height = 30
        b1.Text = i
        b1.Location = New Point(xpos, ypos)
        xpos += 45
        Me.Controls.Add(b1)
        AddHandler b1.Click, AddressOf BuyPizzaHandler
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: If you create the radiobuttons at run-time then you could set their `.Tag` property to the number of the question that they belong to and add a handler for the CheckedChanged. In that handler get the sender's `.Tag` and use that to determine which buton to change the background colour of.

Comment: can u explain me how to do

Comment: If you [edit] the question to show the code that adds the radio buttons, I might be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

To make the button change color when a particular answer is check you could use the disabled property of a bootstrap button.  The button as shown in the code below would be light blue and inactive when the particular answer is not selected and then turn dark blue once the answer is selected.  I will also show you how to make it dark blue and activated when any answer is selected.

Your markup should be something like this:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="row">
        <h5><u><b>What color is the sky?</b></u></h5>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblstSkyColor" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" Style="height: 95px; width: 235px">
                <asp:ListItem Value="Blue" Selected="False">Blue</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="Yellow" Selected="False">Yellow</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="Orange" Selected="False">Orange</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="None" Selected="False">None of the above</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:RadioButtonList>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <button type="button" id="btnNext" class="btn btn-primary" runat="server" disabled="disabled">Next Question</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

And in order for the button to only change if a particular answer is selected your code behind should be something like this:

```
Private Sub rblstSkyColor_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles rblstSkyColor.SelectedIndexChanged
    If rblstSkyColor.SelectedIndex = 2 Then
        btnNext.Disabled = False
    Else
        btnNext.Disabled = True
    End If
End Sub
```

If you want the button to change color and become active when any answer is selected then your code behind should be something like this:

```
Private Sub rblstSkyColor_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles rblstSkyColor.SelectedIndexChanged
    If rblstSkyColor.SelectedIndex = -1 Then
        btnNext.Disabled = True
    Else
        btnNext.Disabled = False
    End If
End Sub
```

I hope this helps.